# How to create Pages with InlinePanel programatically?

Tags: wagtail

Is it possible to create pages and import data programatically? For example with data stored in a csv.  I think django has some kind of bulk_import but I don't know how to do it with Wagtail.

I have a model where the **Page** has an **InlinePanel** to an Orderable class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a write api for Wagtail but why can't you use the built-in django managment scripts?

[Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/02/15/programmatically-populating-a-django-database) has provided a quick overview of how to create custom managment scripts.

Alternatively, if you're just loading in data, why don't you just do a read_csv and loop in through python? 
[Erin Mullaney](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2016/02/15/wagtail-2-steps-adding-pages-outside-cms/) has a quick primer on how to do this as well.

The Crux of this will be writing a quick function that extends the Page class in wagtail.